# Receive order for sequential self tell in akka

Tags: akka, event-sourcing, akka.net

I am using Akka.NET in my project.

And I am wondering, do I have any guarantee that messages will be received in the same order as they were sent to a self actor?

Ex:

```
Self.Tell(msg1);
Self.Tell(msg2);
```

Question: will **msg1** be handled before **msg2**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> will msg1 be handled before msg2?

Yes, if the actor is alive when it sends and receives both messages, and if the actor's mailbox has a FIFO implementation (which is the default). Akka.NET (and Akka) guarantees message ordering on a per-sender basis when using `Tell`, provided that the messages are actually delivered and the recipient's mailbox is FIFO. This is the case even if the sender and recipient are the same actor.